# How does the named let in the form of a loop work?

Tags: scheme

In [an answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12834562/scheme-number-to-list#12841962) which explains how to convert a number to a list the `number->list` procedure is defined as follows:

```
(define (number->list n)
  (let loop ((n n)
             (acc '()))
    (if (< n 10)
        (cons n acc)
        (loop (quotient n 10)
              (cons (remainder n 10) acc)))))
```

Here a "[named `let`](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_6.html#SEC36)" is used. I don't understand how this named `let` works.

I see that a loop is defined where the variable `n` is equal to `n`, and the variable `acc` equal to the empty list. Then if `n` is smaller than 10 the `n` is consed to the acc. Otherwise, "the loop" is applied with `n` equal to `n/10` and `acc` equal to the cons of the remainder of `n`/10 and the previous accumulated stuff, and then calls itself.

I don't understand why `loop` is called loop (what is looping?), how it can automatically execute and call itself, and how it will actually add each number multiplied by its appropriate multiplier to form a number in base 10.

I hope someone can shine his or her light on the procedure and the above questions so I can better understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The basic idea behind a named `let` is that it allows you to create an internal function, that can call itself, and invoke it automatically. So your code is equivalent to:

```
(define (number->list n)
  (define (loop n acc)
    (if (< n 10)
        (cons n acc)
        (loop (quotient n 10)
              (cons (remainder n 10) acc))))
  (loop n '()))
```

Hopefully, that is easier for you to read and understand.

You might, then, ask why people tend to use a named `let` rather than defining an internal function and invoking it. It's the same rationale people have for using (unnamed) `let`: it turns a two-step process (define a function and invoke it) into one single, convenient form.

---

It's called a loop because the function calls itself in *tail position*. This is known as [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). With tail recursion, the recursive call returns directly to your caller, so there's no need to keep the current call frame around. You can do tail recursion as many times as you like without causing a stack overflow. In that way, it works exactly like a loop.

---

If you'd like more information about named `let` and how it works, [I wrote a blog post about it](http://web.archive.org/web/20221205223620/https://dyscour.se/post/58639636506/named-let). (You don't need to read it to understand this answer, though. It's just there if you're curious.)

Comment: Thanks again. Great blog post.

Answer (score 9):

A normal `let` usage can be considered an anonymous procedure call:

```scm
(let ((a 10) (b 20))
  (+ a b))

;; is the same as 
((lambda (a b)
   (+ a b))
 10
 20)
```

A named `let` just binds that procedure to a name in the scope of the procedure so that it is equal to a single procedure `letrec`:

```scm
(let my-chosen-name ((n 10) (acc '()))
  (if (zero? n)
      acc
      (my-chosen-name (- n 1) (cons n acc)))) ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

;; Is the same as:
((letrec ((my-chosen-name 
          (lambda (n acc)
            (if (zero? n)
                acc
                (my-chosen-name (- n 1) (cons n acc))))))
  my-chosen-name)
 10
 '()) ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Notice that the body of the `letrec` just evaluates to the named procedure so that the name isn't in the environment of the first call. Thus you could do this:

```scm
(let ((loop 10))
  (let loop ((n loop))
    (if (zero? n)
        '()
        (cons n (loop (- n 1))))) ; ==> (10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

the procedure `loop` is only in the environment of the body of the inner `let` and does not shadow the variable `loop` of the outer `let`.

In your example, the name `loop` is just a name. In Scheme every loop is ultimately done with recursion, but usually the name is used when it's tail recursion and thus an iterative process.

Comment: I find that an explanation of named `let` in terms of `letrec` to be too unwieldly. I usually prefer to make reference to `rec` (from SRFI 31), which is a nicer syntactic sugar around `letrec`. The translation from unnamed to named `let`, in terms of simply adding a `rec`, is simple and easy to reason about.

Comment: Also, with `rec`, you don't need to explain the acrobatics around "notice that the body of the `letrec` just evaluates to the named procedure so that the name isn't in the environment of the first call". `rec` is easy to reason about. Just use that. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Any of `letrec`, `rec` and named `let` can be used to implement the other two. `letrec` is the most powerful. I would rather just use `lambda` but then you'd have to show the warts of Scheme.

Comment: Scheme has warts?!! :-O I actually just explained the code in terms of an internally defined function. That is `lambda` without actually saying the word `lambda`. :-)

Comment: Anyway, yes, `letrec` is the most powerful of the three (since you can use it to create mutually recursive functions), but it's often overkill (syntactically speaking). In the same way, `case-lambda` is (syntactically) overkill when you have only one "case", and can just use `lambda`. (Don't laugh. In Guile, all lambdas are represented as case-lambdas behind the scenes.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young With warts I mean you cannot implement `letrec`, `define`, named `let`,  or `rec` with just `lambda`  without using `set!`. I don't mind using them but implementing them is no fun.

Comment: [How is `letrec` implemented without using `set!`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8468421/13) Also see: [Fixing Letrec (reloaded)](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/letrec-reloaded.pdf)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young `fix` is very special in that paper, or did I miss something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86562/discussion-between-chris-jester-young-and-sylwester).