# Racket print length of "n" elements in a list

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I need some help to understand tail recursive

```
    #lang racket

   (define (lista x)
   (printf(length(cons x (lista (read)))))
   )

   (lista (read))
```

I can't figure it out how to end the loop of the linked list and then get the length and print this number.

So for example if I have an input of

```
  2
  1
  3
  5
  7
  5
  10
```

It must print 7,but the compiler always message timeout, so I don't know if I'm reading correctly the input or there is another way?

Comment: Since you're using racket, you should use DrRacket. Aside from offering an integrated environment, it will *indent your code automatically*, so when you paste it into SO, select it all, and hit `Ctrl-k` to make it a code block, your code will be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing does not make sense (i will explain below why).
If you are using `length`, you could immediately return the length of the list. The reason why you are having an infinite loop is because you have no stop condition (i.e. when the list is `null?` make an end to the recursion).

I suppose this is an assignment which requires you to do it manually, hence not using `length`.

```
(define (lngth lst)
  (if (null? lst) ; Did we checked the whole list already?
      0           ; This will put an end to the recursion !
      (+ 1        ; Tail recursive call, we add 1 because we call ourselve recusrively with the cdr of the list (hence with a list that is one shorter)
         (lngth (cdr lst)))))
```

Now you can call this procedure, `(lngth '(1 2 3 4 5))` will return 5.

---

```
(define (lista x)
  (printf
   (length
    (cons x 
          (lista (read))))))
```

Your attempt has a few problems. The biggest problem is that it is lacking a stop condition, which is the reason for the endless loop (which is prompting the user for input again and again). Now when you call `lista` you will always encounter a recursive call to itself again and again, because of `(define (lista x) ... (cons x (lista ...)))`.

As I said above, the rest of the code doesn't really make sense.
You are using `cons` instead of `cdr` to traverse through the list, and you are using `length` instead of adding one, `(+ 1 (recursive call))`, for the current element of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I really appreciate that!, I only been using racket for a few days and is so confussing, one last question, a book recommendation? the notes from my teacher are awful

Comment: @Tacocola Google *SICP* (Structure and interpretation of computer programs), it's a classic for Scheme-like courses. However it goes deeper than (only) learning the language, it also comes up with a meta circular implementation of the Scheme language, i.e. implementing a Scheme evaluator, written in... Scheme :)

Comment: @TacoCola, I don't know if it's still around, but there is or was a book called *How to Design Programs* with a gentle introduction to Scheme. There is or was a Racket mode supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

You have no stop condition in the recursion, that's why it goes on without printing the length. You can for example break by looking for a certain input, e.g., "length" to print the length.

```
#lang racket

(define (get-length-of-input)
  (display "Enter a number or get the length (length for length)")
  (let input-loop ((result '()))
    (define input (read-line))
    (cond [(number? (string->number input)) 
           (input-loop (cons input result))]
          [(string=? input "length") 
           (displayln (length result))]
          [else (displayln "unknown input") 
                (input-loop result)])))

; Start the procedure
(get-length-of-input)
```

Here to make it tail recursive an iterative loop is used with a [named-let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work#31909550) . A named-let initializes the loop with an initial value (the empty list `'()`) and starts it of automatically.

Then a case analysis takes place (is the input a number, the string "length" or something else?). If it is a number (checked by trying to convert the input string to a number), this number is added to the local variable `result` and the loop is continued. If the input is "length" the length is printed and the program stops. Otherwise "unknown input" is displayed and the loop continues.