# Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm in Scheme

Tags: algorithm, scheme, knuth-morris-pratt

This is the code to calculate the failure function (how many steps we have to go back) in Scheme, when we use the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm:

```lisp
(define (compute-failure-function p)
    (define n-p (string-length p))
    (define sigma-table (make-vector n-p 0))
    (let loop
        ((i-p 2)
         (k 0))
      (cond
          ((>= i-p n-p)
           (vector-set! sigma-table (- n-p 1) k))
          ((eq? (string-ref p k)
                (string-ref p (- i-p 1)))
           (vector-set! sigma-table i-p (+ k 1))
           (loop (+ i-p 1) (+ k 1)))
          ((> k 0)
           (loop i-p (vector-ref sigma-table k)))
          (else ; k=0
           (vector-set! sigma-table i-p 0)
           (loop (+ i-p 1) k))))
    (vector-set! sigma-table 0 -1)
    (lambda (q)
        (vector-ref sigma-table q)))
```

But I do not understand the part when `k > 0`. Can someone explain it please?

Comment: What's the question? is it about the syntax, or the meaning of `loop`, or the algorithm itself?

Comment: @OscarLopez it is about the meaning of the loop. I do not get that part.

Comment: The code is using a "named `let`", it's simply a shortcut for defining a helper procedure, the name `loop` is arbitrary. The line `(loop ...)` is calling the procedure. It's a way to implement iteration using a recursive call.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work

Comment: Thank you! But I do not get why there is written « i-p (vector-ref sigma-table k) » for k>0?

Comment: "The line (loop ...) is calling the procedure." Is i-p then being set to 2 and k to 0? Or are only the conditions being called?

Comment: @OscarLopez are the conditions actually part of the named let? Or...?

Comment: It's all just a recursive procedure invocation, you should play with a simpler example to understand what's happening. For example: `(loop 1 2)` is calling the `loop` function, passing 1 and 2 as parameters. There's nothing special about it, it's a function call.

Comment: I added an answer explaining how the loop works, with a simpler example. Hope it answers your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're confused with the syntax of a [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work) does a good job explaining how it works, but perhaps an example with more familiar syntax will make things clearer. Take this code in Python, it adds all integers from 1 to 10:

```
sum = 0
n = 1
while n <= 10:
  sum += n
  n += 1

print(sum)
=> 55
```

Now let's try to write it in a recursive fashion, I'll call my function `loop`. This is completely equivalent:

```
def loop(n, sum):
    if n > 10:
        return sum
    else:
        return loop(n + 1, n + sum)

loop(1, 0)
=> 55
```

In the above example, the `loop` function implements an iteration, the parameter `n` is used to keep track of the current position, and the parameter `sum` accumulates the answer. Now let's write the exact same code, but in Scheme:

```
(let loop ((n 1) (sum 0))
  (cond ((> n 10) sum)
        (else (loop (+ n 1) (+ n sum)))))
=> 55
```

Now we've defined a local procedure called `loop` which is then automatically called with the initial values `1` and `0` for its parameters `n` and `sum`. When the base case of the recursion is reached, we return `sum`, otherwise we keep calling this procedure, passing updated values for the parameters. It's exactly the same as in the Python code! Don't be confused by the syntax.

In your algorithm, `i-p` and `k` are the iteration variables, which are initialized to `2` and `0` respectively. Depending on which condition is true, the iteration continues when we call `loop` again with updated values for `i-p` and `k`, or it ends when the case `(>= i-p n-p)` is reached, at this point the loop exits and the computed value is in the variable `sigma-table`. The procedure ends by returning a new function, referred to as the "failure function".