# Difference between two Scheme "makers of an infinite loop"?

Tags: scheme

In the tutorial

[**Call with current continuation patterns**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228576802_Call_with_current_continuation_patterns)
*Darrell Ferguson and Dwight Deugo*, September 2001

the pattern of "breaking out of a potentially infinite loop" using `call/cc` is illustrated with the following Scheme code (slightly modified, made to run in repl.it and commented below):

**Part 1**: "infinitizer" runs "action-function" infinitely often inside a (tail-recursive) loop

```lisp
(define infinitizer
   (lambda (action-function)
      ; "loop" is a closure taking no parameters which calls
      ; "action-procedure" and then calls "loop".
      ; After defining it, just call "loop".
      (letrec
         ((loop
            (lambda ()
               (begin
                  ; ... code to execute before each action would go here ...
                  (action-function)
                  ; ... code to execute after each action would go here ...
                  (loop)))))
         (loop))))
```

**Part 2**: This is the function to be called at the toplevel as `(loop-until 4)` for example. It calls `call/cc` with a `receiver` that invokes `infinitizer` around a counting *action function* that breaks out of the infinite loop by invoking the received continuation once a stop criterium has been reached:

```lisp
(define loop-until
   (lambda (n)
      (let
         ((receiver
            (lambda (exit-function)  ; exit-function will be the "current continuation" at call
               (let ((count 0))            ; count will be mutated using "set!"
                  (infinitizer
                     (lambda ()                 ; this is the action-function
                        (if (= count n)              ; breakoff criterium
                           (exit-function count)         ; call received continuation with exit value
                           (begin
                              (display "The count is: ")
                              (display count)
                              (newline)
                              ; communicate with the next action-function
                              ; instance by POKE-ing count
                              (set! count (+ count 1)
                              ))))))))) ; end of receiver definition
         (call/cc receiver)))) ; call with the above receiver
```

So for example:

```
   (loop-until 4)
The count is: 0
The count is: 1
The count is: 2
The count is: 3
=> 4
```

**Alternate part 1**: It seems that the (here-so-name `infinitizer`, originally named `infinite-loop`) function is overly convoluted. The following seems to work too:

```lisp
(define infinitizer
   (lambda (action-function)
      (begin
         ;;; ... code to execute before each action would go here ...
         (action-function)
         ;;; ... code to execute after each action would go here ...
         (infinitizer action-function))))
```

Is there some difference between the two infinitizers that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Also at repl.it: https://repl.it/@dtonhofer/ContinuationBasedLoopBreakout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of `infinitizer` is more robust. If something redefines `infinitizer` in the middle of it being run, it will still continue to run. The second one will call the new definition when it tries to recurse.

Try the following with both defintions to see the difference:

```
(define (action . args)
  (display "In action")
  (newline)
  (set! infinitizer action))

(infinitizer action)
```

Outside of pathological cases like that, though, they should be equivalent.

---

As an aside, rewriting the first version to use a named let is cleaner:

```
(define (infinitizer action-function)
  (let loop ()
    ;; ... code to execute before each action would go here ...
    (action-function)
    ;; ... code to execute after each action would go here ...
    (loop)))
```

Comment: I didn't even know about "named let". Good one!

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It gets turned into something like the original's `letrec`, just with more convenient, simpler syntax. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work) for more.