# Scheme program to multiply all the elements of a list together

Tags: list, scheme

This program is meant to multiply all the elements of an array together in scheme and output the total but so far it has only been returning 0 as the output.

```
(define (mult-list lst)
  (if (null? lst)
    0
    (* (car lst) 
       (mult-list (cdr lst)))) )
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `0 * <anything>` is still 0, and the multiplication by 0 gets propagated up the function calls since the last function call will always return 0 (which then gets multiplied by the next number, which is still 0, and the next, still 0, etc).

The solution to this would be to return 1 instead of 0, since 1 is the multiplicative identity the same way 0 is the additive identity. Since anything multiplied by 1 is itself, this will mean that the last item in the list gets multiplied by 1 (still = to the last item) which then gets multiplied by the second-to-last item, etc.

Alternatively, instead of returning 1 when the list is empty, you can return the only item in the list (`(car lst)`) when the list has 1 item left in it (`(null? (cdr lst))`).

Comment: We'd still have to return 1 if the list is empty though. :)

Comment: @WillNess true, assuming that you want 1 as the answer for an empty list. The OP doesn't mention what the requirements are for an empty list or if this function is supposed to be able to handle one.

Comment: You already mention it pretty much has to be, from the math perspective.

Comment: Btw both `+` and `*` can be applied with no arguments and will return the identity. eg. `(*) ; ==> 1`. A simple non recursive solution to OPs problem is `(apply * lst)` and it will result in `1`.

Comment: @Sylwester I wonder whether `apply` in Scheme has any limitations as to the maximal allowed number of arguments? (like in Common Lisp)

Comment: @WillNess That is underpecified :-( It would be sensible to have a minimum supporter number of arguments to a form such that if you were to write `(+ 1 2 3 ... n)` you would know how big n could be for it to be portable. `apply` would need to match this minimum. CL compliance [guarantees 50](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/v_lamb_1.htm) so I guess even if you can have lists more than 50 large a shitty implementation might only support 50 elements with `apply`.

Comment: @Sylwester yes I know about the 50 in CL but this question is in Scheme. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(define mul1 (lambda (l) (apply * l)))
(define mul2 (lambda (l) (reduce-left * 1 l)))
(define mul3
  (lambda (l)
    ((lambda (s) (s s l))
     (lambda (s l)
       (or (and (null? l) 1)
           (* (car l) (s s (cdr l))))))))
```

And here I wrote the Peano multiplication that looks more complicated, but in fact it is simpler, as it multiplies by using recursive addition! It uses *only* the operator *SUCC*, the predicate *EQUALP* and the constructor *ZERO*.

```
(define mul/peano
  (lambda (l)
    (define SUCC (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))
    (define EQUALP =)
    (define ZERO 0)

    ;; Peano Axioms
    (define ZEROP (lambda (x) (EQUALP x ZERO)))
    (define ONE (SUCC ZERO))
    (define SUB1 (lambda (x)
              ((lambda (s)
                 (if (ZEROP x) ZERO (s s ONE)))
               (lambda (s x+)
                 (if (EQUALP x x+)
                     ZERO
                     (SUCC (s s (SUCC x+))))))))
    (define ADD
      (lambda (a b r)
        ((lambda (s) (s s a r))
         (lambda (s a c)
           (or (and (ZEROP a) (c b))
               (s s (SUB1 a)
                  (lambda (x)
                    (c (SUCC x)))))))))
    ((lambda (s) (s s l (lambda (total) total)))
     (lambda (s l ret)
       (or (and (null? l) (ret ONE))
           (and (ZEROP (car l)) (ret ZERO))
           (s s (cons (SUB1 (car l)) (cdr l))
              (lambda (r1)
                (s s (cdr l)
                   (lambda (r2)
                     (ADD r1 r2 ret))))))))))
```

Note that I defined `0-1=0`, as this is how Peano does.

Comment: Your continuation calls are not in tail positions with the `or ... and ...` combos like that. They would be, with cond.

Comment: @WillNess  Good point.  The continuations are in tail position for the deepest logical operator, but for the others the result of the continuation is not in tail position, so in general it's not an iterative process, but recursive.  You know the continuation does not return False, but the operators do not know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more a fan of [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), which are, along with arithmetic operations on them, expressed as applications of functions in the elegant and fundamental [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). Note the absence of `*`.

```lisp
(define (mult-list lst)
  (letrec ((mul (lambda (m n) (lambda (f) (lambda (x) ((m (n f)) x)))))
           (church (lambda (n)
                     (if (= n 0)
                         (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x))
                         (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f (((church (- n 1)) f) x)))))))
           (unchurch (lambda (cn) ((cn (lambda (x) (+ x 1))) 0))))
    (let loop ((lst (map church lst))
               (acc (church 1)))
      (if (null? lst)
          (unchurch acc)
          (loop (cdr lst) (mul (car lst) acc))))))

(write (mult-list '(2 3 4)) ; 24
```

You might also be interested in the use of a [named let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work) to express recursion instead of calling the top-level function directly. Very useful in more complicated functions.

Comment: Looks pretty, but without encoding the booleans as Church booleans is not complete yet.

Comment: @alinsoar It also doesn't encode negative numbers.

Comment: Church encoding refers to encoding only the natural numbers, not the integer numbers.

Comment: There's a way to include them.

Comment: Yes, by expanding the representation.  All the mathematics can be encoded using natural numbers.  One expands them to integers, then to rationals, then to real numbers using `Dedekind cut`, then to complex numbers.   But the Church encoding of arithmetic refers strictly to naturals, not to signed integers.

Comment: Would you mind replacing Church encoding in my Peano axioms to rewrite the Peano using Church encoding ?  Maybe it will look fancy.

Answer (score 0):

If we're willing to count in unary as in the other answers, we might as well just count in unary -- with `length`:

```
(define (mult-list lst)
  (length
    (crossProduct
      (map mkList lst))))

(define (mkList n)
  (cond ((> n 0) (cons n (mkList (- n 1))))
        (else (list))))

(define (crossProduct xs)
  (cond
    ((null? xs) (list (list)))
    (else
      (let* ((a (car xs))
             (d (cdr xs))
             (p (crossProduct d)))
        (apply append
          (map (lambda (x)
                 (map (lambda (q) (cons x q))
                      p))
               a))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (mult-list '(2 3 4))
24

> (crossProduct (map mkList '(2)))
'((2) (1))
> (crossProduct (map mkList '(2 3)))
'((2 3) (2 2) (2 1) (1 3) (1 2) (1 1))
> (crossProduct (map mkList '(2 0 3)))
'()
```