# removing 0's from list in Racket

Tags: racket

I am working on an assignment and in the function I am working on I need to remove all 0's from a list. So far I have the function removing all except for the first 0 from the list, I am hoping to receive some guidance as to how I can remove that first 0 as well.

```
(define (trimming list)
        (define thelist '())
            (begin (for-each
                       (lambda (x)
                            (if (member x thelist)
                                #t
                            (set! thelist (cons x thelist))))
                       list)
                   (reverse thelist)))
(trimming (list 0 0 1 3 0 5 0))
```

output:

```
'(0 1 3 5)
```

Comment: Well you shouldn't use `set!` or other destructive procedures. Basically you should cons and recurse or just recurse to skip an element. This looks more like C than Scheme to me.

Comment: It looks like you're thinking in some other language you're familiar with. Scheme requires a different mindset.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code doesn't remove 0's from a list - it removes duplicates so that each element in the returned list is unique. It just so happens that your sample list only has duplicate 0's. It's also pretty unidiomatic - a more typical approach wouldn't use `set!` (You'd usualy just use [`remove-duplicates`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) in Racket, or maybe something like `(set->list (list->set your-list))` if you don't care about order).

The easy way to remove just 0's is to use [`filter-not`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-not%29%29):

```lisp
(println (filter-not zero? '(0 0 1 3 0 5 0))) ; '(1 3 5)
```

If this is for an assignment, though, that probably doesn't meet the learning objectives. You *do* have the right general idea of building up a list of values to return; it just needs to be tweaked to do what you want instead of something else. A more idiomatic explicitly recursive skeleton using a [named let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work) might look like:

```lisp
(define (remove-zeros list)
  (let loop ([list list] [result-list '()])
    (cond
      [(null? list) ; Base case; the input list has been fully processed and you're done
        (reverse result-list)] 
      [some-condition-to-skip-the-first-element-when-true? ; Write this bit yourself
        (loop (cdr list) result-list)] ; go on to the next element
      [else ; Add the first element to the result list; go on to the next
        (loop (cdr list) (cons (car list) result-list))])))
```

Comment: Though personally if `filter-not` wasn't an option, in Racket I'd use [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) if possible before this recursive version. But I figure that's either not allowed either or too advanced at this point in learning Scheme/Racket.