# How to return either a multiplied value in a list or boolean in Scheme (R5RS)?

Tags: list, boolean, scheme, racket, r5rs

So I encountered a problem where I have a list of numbers that I need to multiply out and return that value. However, if the list does not contain numbers or is an empty list, return false. Please note that I cannot use any built in functions and would like to understand from scratch in Scheme R5RS. (Example: make-list is a function in Scheme, but can be done recursively without using the function itself)

I implemented a helper function where the base case is if the list is empty, return false. Otherwise, recursively multiply inside the list. However, this doesn't work since the if condition is returning a boolean whereas the recursive method is returning a function.

Also, I have tried returning my base case into a value which is good except for when I am testing an empty list which is suppose to be #f but a value is returned instead.

An example would be:

```lisp
(mult-this '(2 3 4)) -> 24
(mult-this '(1 2 a b)) -> #f
(mult-this '()) -> #f
```

Here is my psuedo-code (helper)

```lisp
(define multiply-this (lambda (mult)
(if (null? mult)
#f
(* recursively multiply car mult and cdr mult)
```

Comment: This description doesn't make sense. You say "I cannot use any built in functions", but `null?` or `*` are built-in functions. What functions are you actually allowed to use?

Comment: I'm referencing functions that Scheme has implemented. For example, there is a make-list function in Scheme, but the same concept can also be created recursively without using make-list.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bringing up `make-list` at all... it's not something you'd use to multiply the elements of a list together. `fold`, sure, but that's not in R5RS. And you **have** to use at least some built in functions. Are you expected to write your own `*`?

Comment: The last recursion will always return `#f`, but that is not ok as argument for `*`. You also don't check if the element is a number.

Answer (score 1):

One pure-R5RS way:

```lisp
(define (mult-this lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (let loop ((product 1)
                 (numbers lst))
        (cond
         ((null? numbers) product)
         ((number? (car numbers))
          (loop (* product (car numbers)) (cdr numbers)))
         (else #f)))))
```

Basically, it first checks for an empty list, and then for the non-empty case, it recursively iterates over the list using a [named let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work), multiplying together numbers as it goes, and returning early with `#f` if it encounters a non-number value before the end of the list.

Example usage:

```lisp
#;1> (load "mult.scm")
; loading mult.scm ...
#;2> (mult-this '(2 3 4))
24
#;3> (mult-this '(1 2 a b))
#f
#;4> (mult-this '())
#f
```

Comment: @UnknownPeach The key thing to note about this solution is that it is [tail recursive](https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/recursion.html#tail-recursion). That's what allows it to return `#f` as soon as a non-number is found without inadvertently trying to multiply `#f`. The other important observation is that a recursive solution sometimes needs more than one base case.

Comment: @UnknownPeach It also uses [named let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), which is a way to define a recursive helper procedure and immediately call it.